# How to make Franklin U600 USB modem work?

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, 3g

`usb-devices` shows:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=03 Prnt=08 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 10 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1fac ProdID=0150 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Franklin Wireless Corp.
S:  Product=USB Micro SD Storage
S:  SerialNumber=220671445300
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2232:1020  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0425:0001 Motorola Semiconductors HK, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1fac:0150
```

So, my Ubuntu doesn't want to see usb modem as modem, and I am having trouble with it.

Comment: I read some posts from people that made it work with `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=1fac product=0150`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/franklin-u600.conf
```

Paste the following inside the file:

```
########################################################
# Franklin Wireless U600

DefaultVendor= 0x1fac
DefaultProduct=0x0150

TargetVendor=  0x1fac
TargetProduct= 0x0151

MessageContent="555342431234567824000000800108df200000000000000000000000000000"
```

Save and exit. I don't remember if a reboot is necessary, so reboot the computer just to be sure.

Comment: ok, i did it. "lsusb" and "usb-devices" shows the same.

Comment: i just run "sudo usb_modeswitch -c '/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/franklin-u600.conf'" and modem has switched to modem mode. now the LED is lighting continuously. how to connect to the internet now?

Comment: I think you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/95934/65926

Comment: when i click "Detect", it alerts me "No modem was found on your system"

Comment: `dmesg | grep ttyUSB` outputs `[  664.318987] usb 2-1.2.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  664.324402] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0`

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!! `sudo modprobe cdc_acm` in terminal and modem is working! Thanks for your HELP!!!